# Cordova Android build broken after gradle dependencies update issue

Tags: android, maven, cordova, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111

TargetSDKVersion:25

Cordova Android build broken after gradle dependencies update: Execution failed for task ‘:processDebugResources’. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

I recently ran the command “cordova build android” and gradle tried to download some dependecies:

Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
Download https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/support-v4/27.0.0/support-v4-27.0.0.pom

Download https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/customtabs/27.0.0/customtabs-27.0.0.pom

Download https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/support-compat/27.0.0/support-compat-27.0.0.pom

Download https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/support-media-compat/27.0.0/support-media-compat-27.0.0.pom

Download https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/support-core-utils/27.0.0/support-core-utils-27.0.0.pom

Download https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/support-core-ui/27.0.0/support-core-ui-27.0.0.pom

Download https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/support-fragment/27.0.0/support-fragment-27.0.0.pom

Download https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/support-annotations/27.0.0/support-annotations-27.0.0.pom

After that, at the end the build fails with this message:

ERROR: In  FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:font

ERROR: In  FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontStyle

ERROR: In  FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontWeight

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run android (exit code 1)

I tried to find a solution but I didn’t find any post with this.
Any idea???

Comment: `"It is all related to support-v4@27.0.0 and cordova-android@6.2.3 (that was my version) and the cordova-plugin-compat@1.2.0 By upgrading to cordova-android@6.3.0 and removing cordova-plugin-compat. cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-compat --force cordova platform rm android ionic cordova platform "post 83`[See here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/android-build-broken-after-gradle-dependencies-update-execution-failed-for-task-processdebugresources-com-android-ide-common-process-processexception-failed-to-execute-aapt/109982/82)

Answer (score 0):

Remove platform/android then run Cordova build android again